# Network Adapter Card Driver

Tags: networking

I purchased the HP laptop model# 14-DQ0051DX.Before removing Windows 10 I was able to connect to my wi-fi network. After loading Ubuntu 18.04 the laptop does not find any wi-fi networks. What do I need to do to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command. And why 18.04? It will be EoL very soon.

Comment: I used a bootable Ubuntu 18.04 flash drive to load Ubuntu with the intention of updating to 22.04. Unfortunately, I cannot connect to the Internet with the current network adapter driver installed in the HP laptop and Windows 10 was removed.

Comment: So will we see the output that will show what is the adapter? And you can't upgrade 18.04 to 22.04. That was a bad idea. You can use your phone and a USB cable to download a 22.04 iso.